# The list view is not bound to the entries

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want the list view information to be transferred to the entries when taped on the list view item. How do I do this?

How do I bind label information to entries?

Thanks to those who help me!

This is my code for `Entry`:

```
<Label x:Name="name" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
<Entry x:Name="names"  Text="{Binding Es}" />

<Label x:Name="family" FontAttributes="Bold"  Text="Family :" />
<Entry x:Name="namefamily"  Text="{Binding Fl}" />
```

This code my listview

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="listv" ItemsSource="{Binding }"  HasUnevenRows="True"   ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Margin="5" ColumnSpacing="20">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label x:Name="lbl" Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label x:Name="lbl2" Text="{Binding Family}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This code my table:

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
```

This code my vm:

```
public string Es
{
   get => es;
   set
   {
       esm = value;
       var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Es));
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
   }
}

public string Fl
{
   get => fl;
   set
   {
       fl = value;
       var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Fl));
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,args);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where are these Entries located?  Are they on the same page as the ListView, or a different page?  How do you navigate from the ListView to this other page?

Comment: When uset fill in the entries, he enter the view list page with the save button!The entries are on another page and I want the user to re-enter the entries page when the user taps on the list view item, but with the information inside the listview item!(Fill the entries with the data in the listview item.)@Jason

Comment: when you navigate to the next page pass the selected object on the page consturctor

Comment: Can you write an example for me? Because I do not know. @Jason

Comment: please post your code for navigation to the new page when a row is selected

Comment: My entries are inside the  Mainpage, and the name of my ListView page is Wishlist, and my table name is in the Favorite database. I do not know how to act. Thank you very much for your help!@Jason

Comment: I already provided an example below as requested

Comment: Given the names I gave you, how do I place my classes in your code?@Jason

Comment: if you have a **specific** question about my answer, please post a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the selected item via the page constructor

```
listv.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    // you will need to cast this to the appropriate class
    var item = (MyItemClass) e.SelectedItem;

    Navigation.PushAsync(new MySecondPage(item));
};
```

Comment: My entries are inside the Mainpage, and the name of my ListView page is Wishlist, and my table name is in the Favorite database. I do not know how to act. Thank you very much for your help!@Jason

Comment: Given the names I gave you, how do I place my classes in your code?@Jason

Comment: my example is only three lines of code.  What **specifically** do you not understand?  Replace the placeholder names I used with the actual names from your code.  For example, `MySecondPage` should be the name of the page you want to navigate to.

Comment: What should I put instead of (myitemclass)?@Jason

Comment: the name of your model class that is represented by each of row of the ListView